# How do I only copy missing objects between buckets using ruby aws-sdk?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I wrote a script to copy s3 objects from my production s3 bucket to my development one, but it takes quite a long time to run because I am individually checking each object for existence before copying.  Is there a way to diff the two buckets and only copy the objects I need?  Or to copy the bucket as a whole?

Here is what I have currently:

```
count = 0
puts "COPYING FROM #{prod_bucket} to #{dev_bucket}"
bm = Benchmark.measure do 
  AWS::S3.new.buckets[prod_bucket].objects.each do |o|
    exists = AWS::S3.new.buckets[dev_bucket].objects[o.key].exists?

    if exists
      puts "Skipping: #{o.key}"
    else
      puts "Copy: #{o.key} (#{count})"
      o.copy_to(o.key, :bucket_name => dev_bucket, :acl => :public_read)
      count += 1
    end
  end
end
puts "Copied #{count} objects in #{bm.real}s"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with that gem, but you code looks like it is possible to receive an array with all items store in a bucket. Load that list for both buckets and determine the missing files with a simple array operations. Should be much faster.

```
# load file lists (looks up objects in batches of 1000)
source_files  = AWS::S3.new.buckets[prod_bucket].objects.map(&:key)
target_files  = AWS::S3.new.buckets[dev_bucket].objects.map(&:key)

# determine files missing in dev
files_to_copy = source_files - target_files
files_to_copy.each_with_index do |file_name, i|
  puts "Coping #{i}/#{files_to_copy.size}: #{file_name}"

  S3Object.store(file_name, 
                 S3Object.value(file_name, PROD_BUCKET_NAME), 
                 DEV_BUCKET_NAME)
end

# determine files on dev that are not existing on prod
files_to_remove = target_files - source_files
files_to_remove.each_with_index do |file_name, i|
  puts "Removing #{i}/#{files_to_remove.size}: #{file_name}"

  S3Object.delete(file_name, DEV_BUCKET_NAME)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately while 'objects' looks like it would be an array, it is actually just a wrapper that implements enumerable so you can iterate through the objects.  I'm guessing they do this because you can have so many objects in a bucket.  I think I have around 70k objects.  Getting a count on that is also hard because calling .count also has to enumerate every object :(

Comment: Every S3 object has a key that represents its filename. I updated my code example. Please take a look.

Comment: Every iteration, or call to exsits?, has to make an http request to amazon, so I believe that your solution would take about the same amount of time as what I currently have, it would just spend the majority of it's time on the first 2 lines instead of eating the http calls twice each loop.

Comment: Please read my updated code again. The first two lines are only two requests - even if there are thousands of files in each bucket. There are no checks for existence, because `buckets.objects` will only return existing files.

Comment: So it looks like you are onto something :)  Looking at the logs when running the first 2 lines, the gem is smart enough to do batch lookups of 1000, so not quite 1 http request, but much better than 1 per object.  Looks like this will do nicely, thanks!